# Problems while upgrading the rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie to Ruby on Rails. My problem is, I am trying to upgrade the rails version from 1.2.3 to 2.3.4.

I changed the `.rhtml` files to `.html.erb` according to the rails version 2.3.4. I changed the environment and `boot.rb` settings according to the rails version, but when I try to run the application, I'am getting missing template error it is searching for the view with `.rhtml` extension but not for the html.erb. Please kindly help me with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` in the `config/environment.rb` file? It may still be looking for the 1.2.3 gem, as opposed to the 2.3.4 gem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response josh.

 But i have changed the rails version to 2.3.4 in environment.rb file and also i have freeze the gems in the current application with 2.3.4 version.One thing which i cant understand is .... when i run the rails -v command in console it shows the rails version as 1.2.3. . Could you please help me with this? Is there any other file where we should change the rails version. But i have upgraded the rails version.

Thanks in-advance
sam

Comment: If you run the following command, `which gem`, you can see where the gem binary file. If 1.2.3 is using on executable, and you've installed the 2.3.4 gem with another executable (and its not in your path), you might run into problems. Install the 2.3.4 gem with the same executable as with 1.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure whether you have upgraded properly or not by going to script/console and whether it prints out

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
```

or not as you enter the console, that might give you some hints.

Comment: Thanks for your response nas!

 I have upgraded the rails version , but when i run the rails -v command it shows 1.2.3. Is there anything to change?. Could u please help with the steps to be followed to upgrade the rails version from 1.2.3 to 2.3.4?

Comment: Looks like its not installed properly or at all if rails -v shows 1.2.3. In that case, can you just run again 'sudo gem install rails' from the command line. And before doing that do "gem list rails" and see the versions installed.

Comment: I un-installed everything and again I re-installed the rails application. Now it went through nicely.But now having a problem with cache_template_extensions error even after i removed from config/environments/development.rb.

Comment: Can you do a grep/search for cache_template_extensions in your config directory or the whole app and just delete it if you find it anywhere

Comment: Hey nas. I have also come up with the master search of my application for cache_template_extensions error,but nothing was found. Just ,I was blank with this. Is there any other reason for this error to occur?

Comment: I cannot think of any but can you run a gem list command on your system and paste the output here?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a copy of rails in the vendor directory. Also, what does script/about show?

Comment: hello Mr.Ertesvag.  I have checked that whether i have a copy of rails in the vendor directory.I dont have one. when i run the ruby script/about command i am getting error as rails requires ruby gems >=1.3.2. So i run gem update --system command.when i run this command it shows nothing to update.but when i run the ruby script/about command am getting the same error.